# Symfony 4.3 dynamic form for tags solution with Doctrine many to one association

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

First, I'm sorry for my bad english. I need to create form to adding new tags for Article but when I submit form then Request data is not handled in my form because new added tags are not in entity array collection. Is possible to add custom choices to form field with many to one association?

Here is my code:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        dump($builder->getFormConfig()); die;
        /** @var Domain $domain */
        $domain = $this->currentDomainService->getCurrentDomain();

        $builder
            ->add('articleTitle', TextType::class, [])
            ->addEventSubscriber(new TagsChoicesSubscriber())
        ;
    }

class TagshoicesSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => ['preSetData', -50],
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => ['preSetData', -50],
        );
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event, $childName)
    {

        $choices = array();

        /** @var Article $article */
        $article = $event->getData();

        if ($article instanceof Article) {

            foreach ($article->getTags() as $tag) {
                $tags[] = $tag->getTagName();
            }

            $event->getForm()->add(
                'tags',
                ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'choices' => $choices,
                    'data' => $tags,
                    'required' => true,
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank(),
                    ],
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Article
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tags", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $tags;
}
/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Article", inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;
}


        $form = $this->createForm('App\Form\ArticleType', $article);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!

Please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What does _add custom choices to form field with many to one association_ mean?

Comment: @hongsy Thanks for reply. I need edit and add tags for an article which have manytoone association to tag entity. On the frontend I have form with multichoice and option to add new tag which is added and not yet present in tag entity. The problem is how to handle request which contain new tag and of course must be valid. On the choice field I used select2.js.

Comment: @hongsy I found issue for same problem in Symfony repo on github so it's complicated to solve. [https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9310]

Comment: please [edit] your question to add the information you wrote in your comments.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you need to implement is either collection type field, or choice type with multiple set to true, here is [Symfony collection type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and here is [Symfony choice type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html), you will also need a toString function in Tag class.